# How to add the comments box in a single-portfolio.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following problem.

In a file named "single-portfolio.php"  that is working as posts of my wordpress site.   I have been using "facebook comments" plugin for the comments

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

But now I need to go back the old wordpress comments so I tried with:

```
  <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

But is not working.  The comments sections is not appearing. I tried copy the comments.php file in the folder where is single-portfolio.php but doesnt work.

What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `comments_template()` function supports specifying what comments template to use. Try pointing this to your default comments template, usually in the root of your theme folder.

```
comments_template( string $file = '/comments.php', bool $separate_comments = false )
```

Also, bear in mind that the `comments_template()` function:

> Will not display the comments template if not on single post or page, or if the post does not have comments.
>
> Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/